# IOS guided access and app update

Tags: ios, guided-access

I have an app running on ios device in guided mode. These "single-app" devices are shipped to my customers.

So customers can use only my app.

Question is what will happen if I will need to update app? I release new version to appstore - will app on devices be updated as well? even in guided access mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to update application from iTunes. With guided access, you can use only one application from your device. app on device will not be updated with guided access mode..

Answer (score 0):

No ! you need to run updates manually